# How do I automate UI reports in Selenium that are in iframe. These reports can be downloaded to excel and pdf

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Report comes in tabular format.So,what are the options that I can use to automate the reports and validate each cell shown in the report?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch into the desired frame and do operation you desire.

for e.g. : if there is a pdf file in the Iframe switch to frame and and use PDFbox libraries to deal with pdf file.